# How to add key/value pair in to array dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add an array dynamically using jquery. How can i do that.(or)

I want to push the elements in to array like this.

```
 var array = [{"question":"1","answer":"2"}];
```

i want to do that dynamically using for loop i mean
    initially i will add

```
array.push({"question":"1"});
then array.push({"answer":"2"});
```

but I want the elements to in the same array[0] element
but it is taking as array[0],array[1]
How can I do that. I am using for loop to add the elements in to an array.

Comment: If you had several questions, what determines which question object the answer is to be associated with?

Comment: Answers are independent of question. Each question will be having all the six answers

Comment: Can you post more details on how you plan to run your loop? And how within the loop you will get question and answer values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are pushing an answer immediately after, can you not do something like

```
  array[index] = { "question" : array[index].question, "answer": 2 };
```

If not you will have to find some other way of finding the index where the question was pushed and then

Just note that array.push always adds a new object to the array, and does not update it.

Comment: How can we find the index of the pushed element

Comment: I would assume that will be a part of your logic. If you are adding these in a loop, then you could use the last counter. If you are looking for the last item added then index would be the same as array.length - 1. If not, you will need to loop through your array to find the question, and that would give you the corresponding index.